# How do I load some data from database before any view function is called in Flask?

Tags: session, flask, routes

Using Flask, how do I count notifications for a user as soon as the program runs, since the user can begin from any page (route)?

I don't want to tie the code that retrieves this value to any view function in particular, rather I want it to be computed at program initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you can check http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request this sounds like it can match your needs. This will be called only once when someone accesses the webapp for the first time(after start).

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
   log.debug('before first request')
```

If you want to do something more often you can use `before_request` but be careful to not put any heavy lifting in this function.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Do we have any alternative for above solution, like just after start of server, I want to load my static details from DB. Issue with above solution is my first request of the server, will take time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [before_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) decorator:

```
@app.before_request
def do_something():
    # do something here
    pass
```